# Сообщить результаты или о результатах

Tags: падежи

Здравствуйте, уважаемые хранители языка!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой вариант правильный: "сообщить о результатах"
или "сообщить результаты"?

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из словаря: СООБЩИТЬ, что. 1. (также о чём и с придат. дополнит.). Довести до чьего-л. сведения, уведомить, известить.

**Винительный падеж** (сообщить что) ― это скорее *дословное (точное) изложение информации*, например: `Сообщить сводку погоды.  Сообщить решение суда истцу. Сообщить результаты проведенных матчей.`

**Предложный падеж** (сообщить о чем) ― это пересказ достаточно объемной информации в *сжатом виде*: `сообщить родным о результатах обследования больного.`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

Каждый вариант правилен в своём контексте.

*Сообщить результаты* - привести конкретные данные (напр. счёт во всех матчах тура).

*Сообщить о результатах* - привести основные сведения (напр. о чём договорились при встрече).

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ!